# xmlserializer deserialize list containing attributes

Tags: list, deserialization, xmlserializer, xml-attribute

I have xml that part of structure looks like this:

```
<IDList>
    <ValuesList ID="1">
        <Value>1</Value>
        <Value>2</Value>
        <Value>3</Value>
    </ValuesList>
    <ValuesList ID="2">
        <Value>1</Value>
        <Value>2</Value>
        <Value>3</Value>
    </ValuesList>
</IDList>
```

What should be model classes for xmlserializer, so I could deserialize it properly?
On the level of IDList it's quite easy:

```
    [XmlArray("IDList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ValuesList")]
    public List<CValuesList> idList = new List<CValuesList>();
```

but how can I do it when the array element has extra xml attribute?

I tried to do ot in the way shown here:

http://www.codemeit.com/xml/c-xmlserializer-add-an-attribute-to-an-array-element.html

but it didn't worked for me. The elements of the array haven't been deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do that.

- A good solution would be to create an object that contains a list and your properties and inherit/implements IXmlSerializable.
- I've seen some kind of quick and dirty way on this site: http://funcakes.posterous.com/adding-elements-to-lists-in-the-xmlserializer. Since the object doesn't inherit from ISerializable, it won't be serialized as a list by the serializer.